# WebApi - How to respond with a flash file and display in browser

Tags: c#, flash, asp.net-web-api

I would like to show a flash file in browser. Returning a image from an action works (I can see the image in the browser). But when I try to respond with the flash file, the browser tries to download it.

Here is my action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [GET("file")]
    public HttpResponseMessage FlashFile()
    {
        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/flashfile.swf");
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-shockwave-flash");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The browser does not know how to render the object. You will need to endpoints for this. The above one stays as is but you need another one that returns HTML with object markup pointing to the flash file endpoint just like how you would normally render flash on a page

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working.

All you need to do is have this line in your web config under `<handlers>`:

```
<add name="FlashExtension" path="foobar/*.swf" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I changed `[GET("file")]` to `[GET("foobar/{path}.swf")]`

And used this URL in my HTML file like so:

```
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="http://localhost:50000/foobar/flashfile.swf">
<embed src="http://localhost:50000/foobar/flashfile.swf" width="550" height="400"></embed>
</object>
```

This displays my flash video inside the browser using WebApi.